# Getting index at point of failure in try block to print in except block

Tags: python, try-except

I have a scraper that runs through a big list of postal codes and inserts them into a for loop that runs the scraper. The for loop is inside a try block. Sometimes the connection breaks and in those cases I want the scraper to try again for a total of three tries. The problem is I am writing data to the database as the code runs so I don't want it to start at the beginning of the list of postal codes when it retries but rather at the point in the postal code list that it was when the connection broke. I think this would naturally necessitate extracting the postal code index of the for loop from the try block and inserting it into the except block but I have been unsuccessful at this. Part of the issue is I can't figure out how to intentionally break the try block to get the postal code location out of the try and into the except:

Here is what I've got so far as a test:

```
import time
postal_code = ['1','2','3','4','5']
territories_to_scrape = {'territory_name': ['unknown', 'texas', 'louisiana'],
                         'postal_code':['1','2','3']}
def test(postal_code, territories_to_scrape):
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    loop = True
    while loop:
        trycnt = 3
        while (trycnt > 0):
            try:
                for p in postal_code:
                    if p:
                        raise ValueError(f'arg is True {p}')
                    return p
                        
                trycnt = 0
                toc = time.perf_counter()
                print(f"Took {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds or {(toc - tic)/60} minutes, for run to complete for {len(postal_code)} postal_codes in try")
                return p
            except Exception as e:
                if trycnt <= 0: 
                    print("Failed to retrieve: in if of except") # done retrying
                    loop = False
                else: trycnt -= 1  # retry
                time.sleep(0.5)  # wait 1/2 second then retry
                toc = time.perf_counter()
                print(f"Took {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds or {(toc - tic)/60} minutes, for run to complete for {len(postal_code)} postal_codes in else")
                last_postal_code = p
                ind = territories_to_scrape[territories_to_scrape['postal_code'] == last_postal_code].index.values[0]
                territories_to_scrape = territories_to_scrape.loc[ind:]
                print(territories_to_scrape)
test(postal_code, territories_to_scrape)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You have a for loop which may break due to some issue and throw an error. This brings you to the except block where you want to check for how many retries have elapsed, and if you have some retries available, go back in the try block and the for loop, but now start from the index which threw the error the last time. Is this correct? Just confused by your test case.

Comment: @stochastic13 thanks for jumping in! Yes you have it perfectly understood. Sorry I was having trouble describing what I wanted to accomplish

Comment: Alright. Your overall idea of having an outer while loop seems fine. Does your for-loop code throw an error when the connection is lost, or are you asking how to implement a timer to automatically raise an error when a block of code takes a lot of time? If former, your while loop should work (you can explain what is the issue in case such a setup doesn't work).

Comment: @stochastic13 correct! the former. It throws a connection error and I am inputting to the search bar with selenium the zip codes from a list. If the connection is lost then just reinitiating the connection and starting the for loop again is starting it from the beginning of the list causing the same postal codes to be put in all over again instead of starting from the point of failure. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have it almost perfectly well. You just need to begin the for loop from the `p` variable in every attempt. See below for a reduced skeleton code:

```py
postal_codes_to_parse = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
try_count = 0
max_tries = 3
for_loop_starting = 0
while try_count < max_tries:
    try:
        for index in range(for_loop_starting, len(postal_codes_to_parse)):
            p = postal_codes_to_parse[index]
            # do something that might throw an error
    except:
        for_loop_starting = index
        try_count += 1
```

Alternatively, you can have the try_error block inside a single while loop without worrying about having a separate for loop

```py
postal_codes_to_parse = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
try_count = 0
max_tries = 3
index = 0
while (try_count < max_tries) and (index < len(postal_codes_to_parse):
    p = postal_codes_to_parse[index]
    try:
        # do something that might cause an error
        index += 1
    except:
        try_count += 1
```

Comment: this is brilliant! I love the simplicity of the second example you gave. Thank you very much!